# library can't see its own headers

Tags: c++, cmake

FindFoo.cmake:

```
#  Foo_FOUND - system has Foo
#  Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS - the Foo include directories
#  Foo_LIBRARIES - link these to use Foo
#  Foo_VERSION
#  Foo_DEFINITIONS - compiler switches required for using Foo

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(PC_Foo QUIET Foo)

find_path(Foo_INCLUDE_DIR Foo/Foo.h
  PATHS ${PC_Foo_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

find_library(Foo_LIBRARY Foo
  PATHS ${PC_Foo_LIBDIR} ${PC_Foo_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

set(Foo_VERSION ${PC_Foo_VERSION})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Foo
  FOUND_VAR Foo_FOUND
  REQUIRED_VARS
    Foo_LIBRARY
    Foo_INCLUDE_DIR
  VERSION_VAR Foo_VERSION
)

if(Foo_FOUND)
  set(Foo_LIBRARIES ${Foo_LIBRARY})
  set(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Foo_INCLUDE_DIR})
  set(Foo_DEFINITIONS ${PC_Foo_CFLAGS_OTHER})
endif()

mark_as_advanced(
  Foo_INCLUDE_DIR
  Foo_LIBRARY
)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.8)
PROJECT(sandbox)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(sandbox_SOURCES main.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(sandbox ${sandbox_SOURCES})

QT5_USE_MODULES(sandbox Core)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sandbox ${Foo_LIBRARIES})
```

`#include <Bar1.h>` works in my program whereas `#include <Foo/Bar1.h>` doesn't. and the real problem is that i can't build my program because Bar1.h contains `#include <Foo/Bar2.h>` and:

> ...Foo/Bar1.h: fatal error: Foo/Bar2.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

CMake 3.5.1

Comment: With given `find_path` call include directive `#include <Foo/Foo.h>` should work. Probably, you use result of `find_package(Foo)` incorrectly, but you don't show your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: added CMakeLists.txt to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the problem was CMake cache. i deleted everything from the CMakeFiles directory and then CMake couldn't configure the project:

> Could NOT find Foo (missing: Foo_INCLUDE_DIR)

i had to add `PATH_SUFFIXES` to find_path(), and all the problems are gone.